# Rails Rspec test fails when it works in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following code and test that I can't seem to make pass. The code should be auto locking all bookings that have been completed over 24 hours ago.

When I put a pry into the test and run the first line of Booking.auto_lock_guests nothing happens. When I type booking_7 and after type Booking.auto_lock_guests then it changes locked to true. Is this something to do with the way let is set up that it is not showing up in Booking.all? Or is it the way I have written the test?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  def self.auto_lock_guests
    bookings = Booking.where(guests_completed: true, locked: false)
    bookings.each do |booking|
      next unless booking.guests_completed_at <= 1.day.ago
      booking.locked = true
      booking.save
    end
  end


  context 'auto_lock_guests' do
    let(:booking_6) { FactoryGirl.create(:booking, date: Date.today - 5.day, guests_completed: true, guests_completed_at: DateTime.now, locked: false )}
    let(:booking_7) { FactoryGirl.create(:booking, date: Date.today - 5.day, guests_completed: true, guests_completed_at: DateTime.now - 3.day, locked: false )}
    before do
      Booking.auto_lock_guests
    end
    it 'should only lock bookings with a guests_completed date older than a day ago' do
      expect(booking_7.locked).to eq(true)
      expect(booking_6.locked).to eq(false)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to add this into the before action after calling Booking.auto_lock_guests and it worked.

```
before do
  Booking.auto_lock_guests
  booking_7.reload
  booking_6.reload
end
```

Comment: I'm puzzled on how this can work, as I'd be sure that both bookings have not been created at the time when calling `Booking.auto_lock_guests`, but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 1):

`let` is lazily evaluated. When the `before` block is executed there are no records, because the `let` blocks haven't yet been called.

Either change `let` to `let!` to execute the block immediately or call `booking_6` and `booking_7` right before `Booking.auto_lock_guests`

EDIT:

Also you don't check wether the `booking.save` succeeded. If `booking.save` failed - you would never know. :)

The `next unless booking.guests_completed_at <= 1.day.ago` could probably be rewritten as a query: `where(Booking.arel_table[:guests_completed_at].gt(1.day.ago))`

Comment: This didn't seem to fix it but I have solved the problem now. Thanks for the tip about checking save. I am adding that now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate through the records in the first place. In fact it will cause problems as your app scales since pulling all those records into memory will exhaust the servers (or dynos) memory.

You can select the records from the database and update them in a single query:

```
class Booking
  def self.auto_lock_guests!
    bookings = Booking.where(guests_completed: true, locked: false)
                      .where('guests_completed_at <= ?', 1.day.ago)
    bookings.update_all(locked: true)
  end
end
```

The difference in execution time between many individual UPDATE queries and an updating many rows at once can be massive.

To test it you can create multiple records and use change expectations:

```
# use describe and not context for methods.
describe ".auto_lock_guests" do
  # let! is not lazy loading
  let!(:old_booking) { FactoryGirl.create(:booking, date: 7.days.ago, guests_completed: true, guests_completed_at: 3.days.ago, locked: false )}
  let!(:new_booking) { FactoryGirl.create(:booking, date: Date.today, guests_completed: true, guests_completed_at: DateTime.now, locked: false )}

   it 'locks a booking with a guests_completed date older than a day ago' do
     expect do
       Bookings.auto_lock_guests! && old_booking.reload
     end.to change { old_booking.locked }.from(false).to(true)
   end

   it 'does not lock a when guests_completed date is less than a day ago' do
     expect do
       Bookings.auto_lock_guests! && new_booking.reload
     end.to_not change { new_booking.locked }.from(false).to(true)
   end
end
```

Using `change` is a very good idea when testing methods that change the database as they verify both the initial state and the result.

Comment: If you really have to pull the records out of the db make sure you do it [in batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

Comment: Also `context` should be used for context for example `context "when the user is signed in"`. `describe` blocks should be used to describe what it is that you are testing.

Comment: I am doing something after with the bookings that I didn't list here as that portion worked. I am definitely changing it to have the extra where though as that will limit the number of bookings that come through. But I don't think I can do the update_all as I appear to then lose the array of bookings and then can't find the guests within the bookings.

Comment: Well thats the whole idea - the records are not loaded into memory. If you have to load them into memory use `.find_each` but see if you can get it done by using a join query to get the guest as it will be much more performant.